# How to receive all IPV6 packets from a nework interface with .Net Core?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, .net-core, ipv6

In my company, we develop a network product, which acts like a sniffer.

In order to capture all IPV4 packets, we follow the next procedure:

1. create a raw socket (exact code : `new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);`
2. bind it to the IPV4 address of the network interface, port 0 (exact code: `socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, 0));`)
3. If we're on Windows, set the socket to promiscuous mode (exact code: `socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[]{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);`

And this is everything we need in order to capture all IPV4 packets from a network interface. the rest is a simple read operation inside a loop. On Windows, the process has to be executed with admin permissions.

Now, we also want to support IPV6. It's supposed to be easy, but we can't come up with a working solution. Even if nothing throws an exception, the socket is still "stuck" on the read operation. nothing is never received there.

In order to capture IPV6 packets, we modify the above procedure just a bit

1. Create a socket with `Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv6)` (note: using `ProtocolType.Udp` doesn't help either)
2. Bind to a link-local address (example: `socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("fe80::dd37:936f:d87:b70c"), 0));`). Note: adding a scope-id (like `fe80::dd37:936f:d87:b70c%9`) doesn't help either.
3. On Windows, set the socket to promiscuous mode just like the IPV4 procedure.

Another things I've tried:

- setting the socket to dual mode by calling `socket.DualMode = true;` between (1) and (2).
- disabling IPV6-only option on the socket by calling      `socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);` between (1) and (2).

I test this by opening Chrome - Chrome fires an MDNS packet both for IPV6 and IPV4 for its chrome-cast feature. Wireshark (which uses a kernel driver), sees this packet and displays it correctly. My code doesn't unblock from the read operation.

I use Windows 10 that supports IPV6.

An ideas how to read all IPV6 packets from the network interface like in IPV4?
Thanks.

Comment: Listen at IPAddress.IPv6Any : IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0));).

Comment: doesn't help. it makes step 3 throw an exception and if I comment out step 3 it still get stuck on reading.

Comment: @jdweng This doesn't work with raw socket in Windows.

Comment: The IOControl valid values are shown on following pages : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/IOControlCode.cs,dc205b7c4d8d7510 and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/IOControlCode.cs,831bb09b0c1807a6 0x80000000 doesn't seem to be a valid value (new byte[]{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }).

Comment: Don't get window and the net library confused.  The windows socket will work with any type socket.  The managed c# library is very limited on types of sockets that are valid.  It doesn't look like c# have any support for raw sockets.  So your issue is really raw sockets and not IPV6.  Microsoft decided in Net Library to create their own socket class rather than use the Windows Class for sockets.  So using the windows dll for sockets will work.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ws2_32.SendTo

Comment: @jdweng You use ReceiveAll with RCVALL_ON as input buffer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440130/socket-iocontrol-ambiguous-documentation

Comment: @NN_ : Nothing on your link ever said the code posted actually works.  It is a discussion of socket options.  From my experiences the net managed library doesn't allow you to set the IP Header to every possible combination.  So the code will only work if the net allows you to set the options for the protocol you are using.

Comment: It works well with IPv4. You can see a lot of code examples with receiving all traffic using Bind and IOCtl. There is even sample from Microsoft which works with IPv4 but doesn't with IPv6: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/rcvall/rcvall.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use ProtocolType.IP instead of ProtocolType.IPv6.