# Can't get the network layer header when sniffing to an ipv6 address on C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ipv6

When I sniffing to ipv6 addresses, I can only get transport layer headers. However, I got network layer headers when sniffing to ipv4 addresses.

here are my settings:

```
socket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
byteBufferData = new byte[1024 * 64];
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IP, 0)); // a certain address
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
byte[] byteTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] byteOut = new byte[4];
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byteTrue, byteOut);
socket.BeginReceive(byteBufferData, 0, byteBufferData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
```

When I listening to ipv4 addresses, the parameters are `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` and `SocketOptionLevel.IP` respectively.

Comment: What operating system? Maybe try `ProtocolType.IPv6` on the first line? Also `socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));`

Comment: @Charlieface like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532858/10965675), after I changing the ```ProtocolType``` to ```ProtocolType.IPv6```, i can not save a packet anymore. And according to jdweng's comments, may be it is impossible to get the ipv6 header with ```Net`` library at all?

Comment: The .NET library is a fairly bare wrapper over Winsock, so if you can do it in Winsock you should be able to do it in .NET.